# How to use Bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 5 together

Tags: angular, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-hybrid

We are in the process of upgrading an angularJS 1.5 application to angular 15 with the help of hybrid angular (both frameworks will work together till the conversion is finished). For styling, angularJS uses bootstrap version 3.We do not intend to change the styling in Angular and will continue to use the Bootstrap 3 design. But for some UI components in angular 15, we use ngx-bootstrap. To use this with Angular 15, ngx-bootstrap must be version 10. However, ngx-bootstrap 10 requires bootstrap 4 or 5, as it cannot be compacted with bootstrap 3. Therefore, I'm attempting to use bootstrap 3 for application styling and boostrap 5 for ngx-bootstrap.

Any help and suggenstions are appreciated.

Comment: Just don't. This question comes up regularly and there's no good way to do it that won't result in many headaches now and forever. Leave Bootstrap 3 behind. It's been obsolete for _many_ years.

Comment: Agreed. There _might_ be a hacky way to get it working... but it's not worth it.  If you're upgrading this app anyway then it will be using Bootstrap 5 only one day.  You might just have to bit the bullet and re-do things in version 5.  It will be a pain, but moving from AngularJS 1.5 to a (nearly) current version is a **HUGE** upgrade in and of itself.